# Failed insert multiple rows into tables using prepareStatement in controller

Tags: sql, jsp, model-view-controller, jdbc, prepared-statement

My code is shown below. I tried to get multiple input from JSP page and insert them into SQL in the controller. But it doesn't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
String price[] = request.getParameterValues("price");
String isbn[] = request.getParameterValues("isbn");
String title[] = request.getParameterValues("title");
String authors[] = request.getParameterValues("authors");

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
int number = (Integer)session.getAttribute("number");

for(int i = 0; i<number;i++){
     String queryAdd = "INSERT INTO books (price, isbn, title,authors) values" + "(?,?,?,?)";
     PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryAdd);
     stmt.setFloat(1, Float.valueOf(price[i]));
     stmt.setString(2, isbn[i]);
     stmt.setString(3, title[i]);
     stmt.setString(4, authors[i]);
     int result = stmt.executeUpdate(queryAdd);
     out.println(result);
     if(result<=0){
         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Views/error.jsp");
         rd.forward(request, response);
     }
}
conn.close();
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Views/successful.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

My jsp page is here:

```
<form action="addBook.htm" method="post">
    <table style="border:1px solid red; border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Book Title</th>
            <th>Authors</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${sessionScope.number}" step="1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="isbn"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="authors"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Books" />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addSubmit"/>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: First you need to know what is it inside `request.getParameterValues("price");`, secondly, the name in your jsp file should be `<input type="text" name="isbn[]"/>` so it sends an array

Comment: so is the problem in my jsp file? I didnt get the data right from the jsp file?

Comment: Yes, your jsp file is wrong, if you make it like that, only 1 value will be sent(last one), but the controller might be wrong too, I forget about initializing the array in java. Can you post the result of this `System.out.println(request.getParameterValues("price"));` after you fix your jsp file

Comment: Actually, in my original code, it can get all the input and send to servelt, not only the last one. I confirm this by test in debug mode,maybe I think the problem isnt that.

Comment: just found i made a stupid mistake, connecting to wrong db..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your `PreparedStatement` invokation:

```
 String queryAdd = "INSERT INTO books (price, isbn, title,authors) values (?,?,?,?)";
 PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryAdd);
 stmt.setFloat(1, Float.valueOf(price[i]));
 stmt.setString(2, isbn[i]);
 stmt.setString(3, title[i]);
 stmt.setString(4, authors[i]);
```

Fine so far - but not the next line:

```
 int result = stmt.executeUpdate(queryAdd);
```

This calls the `executeUpdate` method of `Statement` - passing in the SQL and ignoring all parameters set. Change it to

```
 int result = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

And you will probably see some results.

Some more notes on your code:

- If there's not too many items in your arrays, you should consider addBatch() and executeBatch() reducing SQL roundtrips.
- Close your statements / Use try-with-resource

Comment: @user5516371 If an answer helped you, you can accept/up-vote that. and it would be nice.